# Getting contents of a csv file on mail to google sheet. Query not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I get daily reports on mail in the form of  csv, contents of which i want to paste in a google sheet. This is the query that i am using.

```js
function importCSVFromEmail() {
  var sheetName = "Median Values"; // Modify this to match the sheet name where you want to paste the data
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - 2);
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  var day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
  var prefix = "Mfare Report";
  var subject = prefix + " " + year + "-" + month + "-" + day; // Construct the subject based on the current date and prefix
  Logger.log("Subject: " + subject); // Add this line to log the subject
  var threads = GmailApp.search("subject:" + subject + " is:unread");

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      var attachments = messages[j].getAttachments();
      for (var k = 0; k < attachments.length; k++) {
        var attachment = attachments[k];
        if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {
          var csvData = attachment.getDataAsString();
          var csv = Utilities.parseCsv(csvData);
          sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, csv.length, csv[0].length).setValues(csv);
          messages[j].markRead();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Need help in sorting this out

I ran this query on app script but didnt work.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of `I ran this query on app script but didnt work.`?

Comment: When asking a question, try to be as specific as possible. Saying "didnt work." isn't really specific at all and doesn't help anyone know what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Does it generate any error? If not, you will have to check each variable step by step, to verify if you are getting the correct information.